# Arboles ordenacion postOrden c++

Tags: c++

Estoy estudiando árboles en c++ y hay algo que no comprendo, tengo esta función:

```
 void postOrden(Nodo *arbol){
        if (arbol == NULL){
            return;
            }
        else {
            postOrden(arbol->izq);
            postOrden(arbol->der);
            cout<<arbol->dato<<" - ";
            } 
        }
```

Recibe el árbol como parámetro de tipo Nodo que es una estructura que contiene dato, izq y der. Entiendo que el ordenamiento postOrden primero muestra los datos del lado izquierdo, después el derecho y al final la raiz pero no comprendo la recursividad en este tema. Cómo es que muestra los datos del lado izquierdo luego derecho si el cout solo mostrará un dato después de que árbol sea null? no comprendo como se van imprimiendo los datos y al final la raíz

Answer (score 4):

¿Alguna vez has leído un libro de [Elige tu propia aventura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elige_tu_propia_aventura)? Las funciones de los lenguajes de programación se comportan de manera parecida.

> 1. [Marco Medina](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/142148/marco-medina) entró en la lúgubre cueva y halló al terrible Kraken.
> 2. Si no es la quinta vez que entras en la lúgubre cueva grita "¡Sapristi!" y sal de la cueva, vuelve a la línea 1.
> 3. Si es la quinta vez que entras en la lúgubre cueva enciende la luz y reta al terrible Kraken a una partida de Piedra-Papel-Tijera-Lagarto-Spock.

Si sigues las instrucciones, gritarás ¡Sapristi! cuatro veces y después encenderás la luz. ¿Cómo es que sólo enciendes la luz la quinta vez si la orden "enciende la luz" está justo después de entrar en la lúgubre cueva? Pues porque **antes** de encender la luz sales y entras de la lúgubre cueva.

---

Vamos a suponer que tu función `postOrden` recibe el puntero `p`:

```
                  /--> |  p->izq  |
                 /     | izq -----+--> nullptr
                /      | der -----+--> nullptr
|     p    |   /       | dato = 1 |
| izq -----+--/
| der -----+--\
| dato = 0 |   \
                \
                 \
                  \--> |  p->der  |
                       | izq -----+--> nullptr
                       | izq -----+--> nullptr
                       | dato = 2 |
```

La ejecución será la siguiente:

```
 void postOrden(Nodo *arbol) {
 /* 1 */if (arbol == NULL){
 /* 2 */    return;
            }
        else {
 /* 3 */    postOrden(arbol->izq);
 /* 4 */    postOrden(arbol->der);
 /* 5 */    cout<<arbol->dato<<" - ";
            } 
        }
```

- 1 `p` no es `NULL`.
- 3 Llama a `postOrden` con `p->izq`.

  - 1 `p->izq` no es `NULL`
  - 3 Llama a `postOrden` con `p->izq->izq`.

    - 1 `p->izq->izq` es `NULL`.
    - 2 salir.
  - 4 Llama a `postOrden` con `p->izq->der`.

    - 1 `p->izq->der` es `NULL`.
    - 2 salir.
  - **5 Imprime `p->izq->dato`**.
- 4 Llama a `postOrden` con `p->der`.

  - 1 `p->der` no es `NULL`
  - 3 Llama a `postOrden` con `p->der->izq`.

    - 1 `p->der->izq` es `NULL`.
    - 2 salir.
  - 4 Llama a `postOrden` con `p->der->der`.

    - 1 `p->der->der` es `NULL`.
    - 2 salir.
  - **5 Imprime `p->der->dato`**.
- **5 Imprime `p->dato`**.